# Access path from indexes

Tags: sql, oracle

I have here a litle exercise about Indexen but I am not sure how to make it.

```
What is the access path for:

SELECT instituteID, totalPrice 
FROM Purchases_XX
WHERE totalPrice > 59 AND spDateID = 2 

if you get this index:
create index i_purchase1 on Purchases (instituteID,spDateID, totalPrice)


And what is the access path for:
SELECT *
FROM Purchases_XX
WHERE totalPrice > 59 

if you get this index:
create index i_purchase1 on Purchases (instituteID,spDateID, totalPrice)
```

Like you can see it are 2 different exercises, I just learned how to make an index and that it make your researches go quicker. But I am stuck with "What is the access Path"

If you have any idea, your free to post.
Thnx in advance.

Comment: Read books or Oracle documentation. Question is so bad. Nobody wants to do YOUR work for YOU.

Comment: Well can you atleast tell me where to start looking or a litle example so I have any idea how to start...?

Comment: Go to www.google.com, enter "oracle access path". First link.

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, maybe an index skip scan if there are very few unique instituteid's, maybe a fast full index scan.

For the second one, maybe a fast full index scan if the table rows are on average very much longer than the index and has only a few rows with totalprice greater than 59.

Neither of the indexes looks very suitable.

Research it here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29597_01/server.1111/e16638/optimops.htm#i82080